# Using df.query() to extract rows from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame *df* which contain three columns: `['mid','2014_amt','2015_amt']`

I want to extract rows of a particular merchant. For example, consider my data is:

```
df['mid'] = ['as','fsd','qww','fd']
df['2014_amt] = [144,232,45,121]
df['2015_amt] = [676,455,455,335]
```

I want to extract the whole rows corresponding to `mid = ['fsd','qww']` How is this best done? I tried with the below code:

```
df.query('mid== "fsd"')
```

If I want to run a loop, how can I use the above code to extract rows for specified values of `mid`?

```
for val in mid:
           print df.query('mid' == "val"')
```

This is giving an error, as `val` is not specified.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

```
df.query('mid in ["fsd", "qww"]')

   mid  2014_amt  2015_amt
1  fsd       232       455
2  qww        45       455
```

---

**Option 2**

```
df[df['mid'].isin(['fsd', 'qww'])]

   mid  2014_amt  2015_amt
1  fsd       232       455
2  qww        45       455
```